# Techniques to get greater levels of zoom in a iphone 3D engine?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, size, zooming, textures

I have a 3D globe I'm rendering using a single 2048x2048 texture (supposedly the max resolution for iphone/ipad).  This limits the amount of zoom possible where at some point the 2048x2048 doesn't give me enough resolution. Can someone point me to some LOD techniques that may be used to achieve better resolution on zoom?  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it simply called "Having more than one texture, each covering parts of the globe"? :) As for loading higher resolutions as you zoom, have a look at mipmaps (don't know if that's available in OpenGL ES)

Comment: @roe What's mipmaps got to do with it?

Comment: @Andreas; probably not much if aliasing isn't a problem when using too high resolution images. Although, what he is looking for is probably a scheme similar to mipmapping, albeit probably a bit less automatic..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at a technique called "Virtual Texturing". It is used in video games such as Rage developed by id Software to simulate very large textures.

Googling these terms should give you plenty of results such as this one: http://www.silverspaceship.com/src/svt/

Hope this helps.

Comment: The following link points to id's presentation about the technique: http://www.scribd.com/doc/18241638/id-Tech-5-Challenges